# Odd behave in Django-cms : top toolbar appearing twice

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a simple installation of Django 1.4 and django-cms . I insert a template really simple , some css and an image. No other things are installed at the moment. I have a placeholder on one of my template and when I go to mypage?edit I can see the the place button of the toolbar and my placeholder but the toolbar is twice: 2 loggin, 2 edit mode button, 2 publish and so on....I have no error in console.
What can cause that?

Thanks!

Comment: A double include of the toolbar files, I would mention.

Comment: solved out some how...the position of my JS files in the base.html template wasn't right and causing somehow that problem !